# Fill NaN with average based on index of type period[M]

Tags: python, date, pandas-groupby, period

I have a `df` in which the index is of dtype `period[M]` that looks like this:

| month | outcome | MKT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | W | 6 |
| 2020-01 | W | 4 |
| 2020-03 | W | NAN |
| 2020-03 | L | NAN |
| 2020-02 | L | 4 |
| 2020-02 | L | 7 |

I want to replace all NAN values of the column `MKT` by the average of the values in the column when the month and the outcome are the same. An expected result for these samples is:

| month | outcome | MKT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | W | 6 |
| 2020-01 | W | 4 |
| 2020-03 | W | 5 |
| 2020-03 | L | 5.5 |
| 2020-02 | L | 4 |
| 2020-02 | L | 7 |

I have tried the following:

```
df["MKT"] = df.MKT.fillna(groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).df.MKT.mean())
```

But I get the error

> NameError: name 'groupby' is not defined

I have seen some solutions for the case of datetype, but I have dtype `period[M]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> replace all NAN values of the column MKT by the average of the values in the column *when the month **and** the outcome* are the same

This sounds like you are looking for

```
df.MKT = df.MKT.fillna(df.groupby(["month", "outcome"]).MKT.transform("mean"))
```

but your expected output looks like

```
df.MKT = df.MKT.fillna(df.groupby("outcome").MKT.transform("mean"))
```